# How to push one video to two or more different clients at the same time

Tags: javascript

I made a local video streaming service and I want to know how to push one video to more than one client at once - what are my options?

Ps. I'm not it's local so I'm not really pirating videos to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Use Socket.IO and NodeJS Server or another Server Which can create Socket

Comment: Could You Send A Guide Please? Thanks For Your Answer btw.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvlyzDZDEq4. It's Not about this but identity logic